How to configure the width of a DialogFragment with Compose content?
In my Android application the "about" screen is set up as a dialog as described here:
class AboutDialog : DialogFragment() {

    // ...   

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, container, false).apply {
        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.about_view).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                AboutScreen()
            }
            isClickable = true
        }
    }

}

... the about_dialog.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/about_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

... the AboutScreen composable:
@Composable
fun AboutScreen {
    MyTheme {
        Scaffold { contentPadding ->
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .padding(contentPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                Column {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The dialog (blurry part in the screenshot) expands to some percentage of the screen so that the background screen is visible on the left and right sides.

How can I configure the width of the dialog?

The following function does the trick for me:
... in AboutDialog.kt:
private fun Window.setPercentageWidth(percentage: Int) {
    val metrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    val width = (metrics.widthPixels * (percentage / 100f)).toInt()
    setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
}

... in the AboutDialog class:
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    dialog?.window?.setPercentageWidth(70)
}

I was worried about flickering due to the order of the Android lifecycle calls ...

onAttach -> onCreateView -> onStart -> setContent

... but setContent is invoked late for me. No flickering observed.

You can use below.
class AboutDialog : DialogFragment() {

    // ...   

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, container, false).apply {
        //Sets the dialog width to targetWidth
        (dialog as Dialog).apply {
              setOnShowListener {
                  val targetWidth = 400
                  window!!.attributes = window!!.attributes.apply {
                       width = targetWidth
                  }
              }
         }
        
        //rest of your codes
    }

}




Edit:
OR you can set a custom theme to the dialog fragment. This will set the width even before showing the dialog.
//You need to extend AppCompatDialogFragment instead of DialogFragment
//to make the custom AppCompat theme work
class AboutDialog : AppCompatDialogFragment() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         //Apply custom theme
         setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog)
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      }
 
     //rest of your codes
   

}


res/values/styles.xml
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">

        <!--You can set here your target width - either in dp or % (of display) -->
 
        <!--Portrait-->
        <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">50%</item>
       <!--  <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">50%</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">50%</item>

        <!--Landscape-->
        <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">50%</item>
        <!--  <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">50%</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">50%</item>

    </style>
</resources>


Thank you. The app crashes, though: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Dialog cannot be cast to androidx.activity.ComponentDialog

dialog as Dialog does not crash. setOnShowListener however seems a bit too late - first the dialog becomes visible then its width is adjusted - there should not be a flickering.
